# Unknown class error on iPhone, but not in Simulator

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my project on my iPhone:

```
Unknown class LoginView in Interface Builder file.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "LoginView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

I created a LoginView .xib file earlier, but deleted it, and now it seems to still be trying to access it. I made sure it's not referencing LoginView anywhere in my project, but I'm still getting the error. The weird thing is it only happens on the device, not in the simulator.

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I can see this is related to some XIB file which is still referencing a class LoginView. Got to Find options and select "all candidate files".

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://cl.ly/2C2a0L072T2h0Q3s1T1d I searched for "LoginView", but nothing comes up

Comment: Exactly, well just a try. I think I was wrong. Next try:-) What is about the file system, did you search for LoginView.xib  or .nib? I had this a few times,  deleting in XCode and accidentally miss to click remove button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing a clean all and also make sure that the file was deleted, rather than just removed from the project.

Comment: That did it, thanks! For others: to clean all, make sure you stop any currently running code and go to Build > Clean All Targets